# AngularJS: Response header returns empty object

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS $http post methods response header to manipulate location parameter. When I inspect the browser; it shows that response header containing location parameter with value but when it comes to AngularJS response header object it dosent containing anything at all but empty object.

```
$http.post(MNS_DOMAIN + SERVER.MESSAGE_PROXY, JSON.stringify(payload))
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.messageLocation = headers();

            $scope.success = SUCESS_DATA_SENT;
            clearFormData();
        })
                .error(function(errorCallback) {
            $scope.error = errorCallback;
            console.log("Error " + errorCallback);
        })
                . finally(function() {
            console.log("REST call for send message");
        });

        console.log($scope.error);
    };
```

Comment: If you console headers what does it gives?

Comment: If console it it gives [object Object] with empty properties.

Comment: I sorted the issue by adding "Access-Control-Expose-Headers":"Location" in response server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using the headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.

You can do something like this:

```
var headerObject = data.headers();

and access the properties like headerObject["propertyName"] to get the value.
```

[$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)